# Apache Phoenix - Create view on existing phoenix table with additional calculated field

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I want to create a view in apache phoenix on an existing phoenix table and with an additional column. The following create view statements are throwing error:

```
CREATE VIEW  SCHEMA01.OSLE_VW (EVENTTIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP) AS SELECT *, CAST(TO_NUMBER("EVENTTIME") AS TIMESTAMP) EVENTTIMESTAMP FROM SCHEMA01.OSLE;
CREATE VIEW  SCHEMA01.OSLE_VW AS SELECT *, CAST(TO_NUMBER("EVENTTIME") AS TIMESTAMP) EVENTTIMESTAMP FROM SCHEMA01.OSLE;
```

> Error: ERROR 604 (42P00): Syntax error. Mismatched input. Expecting
> "FROM", got "," at line 1, column 70 (state=42P00,code=604)
> org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 604
> (42P00): Syntax error. Mismatched input. Expecting "FROM", got "," at
> line 1, column 70.

Please suggest if it is possible to achieve this in phoenix.

Answer (score 0):

After going over the documentation and Phoenix pro book, I have come to understand that Phoenix does not allow additional computed fields in the view. A view can have additional fields other than the underlying table. The values of these fields need to be provided while adding data via the **view** upsert statements. The additional fields cannot be computed based on the existing table data. Thus the additional fields in Phoenix act very differently from the commonly used relational database systems.